# How to find duplicate URLs in the database?

Tags: product-urls

```
Magento 2.4.2-p1
Smartwave Porto theme
```

We migrated from Magento 1.9.4 to Magento 2.4.2-p1. We keep getting the following Error when working with products:

```
The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists. 

To resolve the conflict, you can either change the value of the URL key field 9located in the Search Engine Optimization section to a unique value, or change the Request Path fields in all locations listed below:
```

and a list of usually 4 URLs

**Is there a script I could run in phpMyAdmin to get a list of all duplicate URLs so that I could go through them all and change the URL of each product?**

Comment: Probably you can use the following extensions to figure out and resolve the issues. find issues with urls: https://github.com/baldwin-agency/magento2-module-url-data-integrity-checker

Comment: to regenerate catalog urls: https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls

Answer (score 4):

1. To get the Product URL key duplicates. Please check the attached custom script in which the default store view code will be 0 and it will check all the products i.e enable, disable,is_salable, etc. If you want to change the store view code, Please change it in the code before you execute. [Git Link for the custom script.](https://gitlab.com/knowledgetransfer/m2customscripts/-/tree/master/DataDuplicateCheck)
2. Once the script is executed you can see the URL key list with multiple SKUs which have the same URL key.

Comment: Thanks hugely for that. I was getting these errors when importing products after migrating product data from Magento 1 and it was driving me crazy. There are dozens of solutions to this problem out there but none of them helped me. Not only did this script allow me to finally start fixing the problem, it also allowed me to understand what was actually happening. I can't help thinking that a more useful error message from Magento would have saved a lot of people a lot of grief.